# How do i update and share the data between two non related components using a service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, data-sharing

I have a calendar view from which I will get a "Calendar ID" on selecting a date and will redirect to the home page. I have to pass that calendar ID to home page.

I have used a service to update and get the calendar ID

**event-calendar.component.ts**

```
selectChange(event,content){
    this.selectedvalue= event.target.value;

    this.http.get(this.calendarUrl+this.formattedDay).subscribe((res)=>{
      this.calendarID=res;
      this._dataservice.setSelectedCalendarId(this.calendarID); 
    },
    (err)=>{
      this.calendarID=err
    });

    if(this.selectedvalue == '1'){

        this.router.navigate([''], { queryParams: { load: 'true' } });
        this.modal.dismissAll(content);
    }
    else if(this.selectedvalue == '2'){
      this.router.navigate([''],{ queryParams: { load: 'stop' } });
      this.modal.dismissAll(content);
    } 

  }
```

Dataservice.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class DataserviceService {

   public calendarId = new Subject<any>();
   selectedCalendarId = this.calendarId.asObservable();


   constructor() {
   }

   setSelectedCalendarId(id){ // set mailid using subject
    this.calendarId.next(id); alert(id);
  }
}
```

and finally my analytics.component.ts

this is where I want to get the Calendar ID;

```
ngOnInit() {

    this._dataservice.selectedCalendarId.subscribe(id => this.calendarId = id)

    console.log(this.calendarId);
}
```

I am getting the data as "undefined"

Please help me achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the service singleton, or everytime a component will try to access it a new istance of the service will be created. In in the service just change this:

```
@Injectable()
```

In this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

**DOCS:**

1. [Singleton Service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)
2. [hierarchical-dependency-injection](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection)